# How to run 2 thread groups in loops using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 thread groups

1. Authorization:
   user logs in gets bearer token - I set a property in BeanShell script as 'Bearer'
2. Api request:
   In Beanshell preprocessor m getting bearer token from authorization and setting in request

Both these threads work properly with user count 1
Now I want to send 5 Api requests for 5 users

eg.

````
var authorizationusercnt = 5;
var apiRequestusercnt = 5;
for(i=0;i<authorizationusercnt;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<apiRequestusercnt;j++)
   {
      //run api HTTP request
   }
}
 ```
Please help me how can i do this in Jmeter?
````

Comment: Why do you want to use 2 thread groups in this case..? You simply can use 2 Transaction Controllers.. Please comment if there is any special case to use 2 Thread Groups..

Comment: Thanks for replying Kalaiselvan. I used a loop controller, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use 2 thread groups there, just put the logic which logs in and gets the token under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

[image]

So given you set 5 threads and 5 loops in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you will get 1 authorisation request followed by 5 API requests for each user

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)